# How to make an authentication in app maui valid if app is running or in focus?

Tags: android, maui, fingerprint, maui-blazor

I have biometric authentication implemented with the Nuget Fingerprint package in my MAUI project with Blazor, but I am unable to validate the authentication to last as long as the app is running. Does anyone know or know how to do it or recommend something?

I've tried using a token but haven't been able to get it to work

Comment: What "running", "in focus", "token", "fingerprint" have in common? Also, are you asking how to make save the authorization request in bool variable? I am confused. Typically the programmer is the one who decides if application is authorized or not. If you do not want to open another authorization request, just do not.

Comment: Which NuGet Fingerprint package do you use?

Comment: Plugin.Fingerprint

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try https://github.com/FreakyAli/Plugin.Maui.Biometric